# ¿Por qué mi ventana no aparece? Aun asi el programa si que va corriendo

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Soy nuevo en python y necesito saber por que el programa no da fallos pero la ventana asignada a este (gamewindow) no aparece. Y el problema no es el mainloop porque aun que este esté presente la ventana no aparece.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
#To "print" the command is (something).pack

#Declaration of Variables
PointsUp = 0
PointsDown = 0
ButtonStartPressed = False
ButtonOptionsPressed = False

#Dcelaration of Window and his parameters
gamewindow = tk.Tk()
gamewindow.title("Pong")
gamewindow.geometry('1200x800')#(X * Y)
gamewindow.configure(background='Black')
gamewindow.resizable(width=False,height=False)

#Text declarations
PointsUpText=tk.Label(gamewindow,text="POINTS ="+str(PointsUp)+" "*378,bg='black',fg='white')
PointsDownText=tk.Label(gamewindow,text="POINTS = "+str(PointsDown)+" "*378,bg='black',fg='white')

#Button declarations
ButtonStart=tk.Button(gamewindow,text="Start",padx=50,pady=30)
ButtonOptions=tk.Button(gamewindow,text="Options",padx=50,pady=30)

#In-Game main loop
while not ButtonStartPressed and not ButtonOptionsPressed:
    ButtonStart.pack()
    ButtonOptions.pack()

gamewindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné el problema, simplemente no puedo usar un bloque while dentro del mainloop de la ventana (aun que sigo sin saber porqué)

```
#Imports
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
#To "print" the command is (something).pack
#Separate Text in .pack = padx and pady

#Declaration of Variables
PointsUp = 0
PointsDown = 0
ButtonStartPressed = False
ButtonOptionsPressed = False

#Dcelaration of Window and his parameters
gamewindow=tk.Tk()
gamewindow.title("Pong")
gamewindow.geometry('1200x800')#(X * Y)
gamewindow.configure(background='grey')
gamewindow.resizable(width=False,height=False)

#Text declarations
PointsUpText=tk.Label(gamewindow,text="POINTS ="+str(PointsUp)+" "*378,bg='black',fg='white',font="Helvetica 50")
PointsDownText=tk.Label(gamewindow,text="POINTS = "+str(PointsDown)+" "*378,bg='black',fg='white',font="Helvetica 50")

#Button declarations
ButtonStart=tk.Button(gamewindow,text="Start",padx=109,pady=60,font="Helvetica 50",command=StartGame)
ButtonOptions=tk.Button(gamewindow,text="Options",padx=100,pady=60,font="Helvetica 50",command=OptionsGame)
ControlSelectUpPlayerLeft=tk.Listbox(gamewindow,)
ControlSelectUpPlayerRight
ControlSelectDownPlayerLeft
ControlSelectDownPlayerRight
#Command declaration
def StartGame():
    ButtonStart.destroy()
    ButtonOptions.destroy()
    ButtonStartPressed

def OptionsGame():
    ButtonStart.destroy()
    ButtonOptions.destroy()
    ButtonOptionsPressed

#Game program
ButtonStart.pack(pady=100)
ButtonOptions.pack()

gamewindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bienvenidx c: Es que tu while NO estaba adentro del mainloop de Tkinter. El mainloop de la ventana se inicia en (como dice su nombre) `gamewindow.mainloop()`. Cuando se ejecutaba tu while, el código se trababa antes de que iniciases el mainloop de la ventana con `gamewindow.mainloop()`.

Comment: No puedes meter ningún código de Python dentro del mainloop. Lo que si se puede hacer es enlazar una función a un evento. Como que se ejecute la funcion x cuando el usuario presiona la tecla a. Y luego esa función es llamada dentro del loop de la ventana.

Comment: Ok, gracias por tu respuesta